# Sum of days between dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column where its cells are formatted as "dd hh:mm:ss"

When I'm going to do the totaling of the lines and the number of days "no" exceeds 31, the sum works perfectly, but when the sum of days exceeds 31, Excel considers that we have changed the month and the value of days is reset.

Command:

```
=SUM(B1:B2)
```

Result:

```
           sum of dates                       sum of dates
      "no" exceeded 31 days                 exceeded 31 days

       A         B                        A         B
1            15 00:00:12             1          15 00:00:12
2            16 01:39:48             2          19 01:39:48
             -----------                        -----------
    Total    31 01:40:00                Total   05 01:40:00 ----> here i need it to be "34 01:40:00".
```

How to make Excel continue summing correctly after days count is greater than 31? ex: 32, 33, 34, 35...

Note:
The cell that will count the total value, which must always be in the format "dd hh:mm:ss" because I will use it in another calculation in my table.

Comment: If you format `B1:B3` as numbers, what are the values in each of the cells?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try adding [ ] around the DD, i.e., `[DD]` for the formatting.</s>

EDIT: Apologies, I'm away from my PC (on a Chromebook at the moment), so I couldn't verify.  It seems I mistakenly recalled the similar usage for `TIME` datatype digits, such as [hh]; however, it seems the `d` in date data types does not have the equivalent functionality.

Instead, what you can do is use a formula like this:

=text(INT(A3),"#,#00")&" "&TEXT(A3,"hh:mm:ss")

Due to the nature of how Excel processes time, you can treat the number of days as an integer, then concatenate the remainder of the time digits as text.  Both of these can be formatted using the `TEXT()` function.

Comment: The answer is not obvious or verifiable. It may get deleted. You could improve it by giving an example of use, explaining what it does and linking a refetence to its description.

Comment: I don't have a PC accessible to me at the moment, so if someone can verify that this works for me I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @Arctiic I couldn't reproduce your solution... it's too confusing for me! Note: the cell that will contain the total value, which must always be in the format dd hh:mm:ss because I will use it in another calculation in my table.

Comment: @Blind Spots when I change the formatting to numbers, the value in decimals 65.07 is correct compared to the amount of days, the problem is that when I change the cell format to "dd hh:mm:ss" Excel ignores it the days value above 31 and it shows "05 01:40:00"!!!

Comment: What I'm saying is **not** to format the date string as "dd" and just leave it as a plain whole integer.  The way that Excel stores time makes it so that 24 hours equals "1" anyway, so it will end up displaying the correct number of days  even without the date formatting.

Comment: For  your other calculations, you can convert the formatting over at runtime for your calculations?  Or am I missing something to that regard?

Comment: @Arctiic I understand your logic, what is happening is that it is not working in my excel spreadsheet!... you still have no access to your excel?... if you can, try to do it in yours and show it in your answer . Remember my excel is version 2016 ok?